# React props vs redux vs hooks and context api

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I need to implement a SPA whose components are going to interact with their local state and are minimum the cases in which these state is going to be nedded by other components. For example: the employee component contains state about an employee that only will be shared with the employee's component children but not from other different component in the site. Until now my idea is to create 'stores' in the parent component (Employee for example) implemented with hooks and Context Api, for achieving max development speed and clarity in code. What do you think?

Comment: I would go with redux as it may come handy even in minimal use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ultimately subjective, and it sounds like you're already leaning towards using the Context API.  We made a similar decision on our current project; the amount of data that needs to be shared across the application is quite small, so adding the additional code, dependencies and file structures for Redux did not seem worth it.

But if you are using Context, make sure you have thoroughly plotted out the data flow of all parts of your application, as it's easy to overlook something and run into a situation where getting the data outside of a particular module can become very difficult.  Also consider its size.  If it's a large application, the benefits of centralizing your state changes for easy testing and debugging are not negligible, and Redux can also help boost performance by automatically memoizing connected components.

Again, this is ultimately opinion-based, but I think it's a concrete and common enough concern with React apps that it bears some discussion, though this might end up being closed.

Comment: Yeah it was closed. :( We are going forward with Context API and hooks. Redux seems like and overkill for want we need. Because the app is big, but the data flows are almost independent.